# Cannot set tokenValiditySeconds in Spring-Acegi

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use acegi-security-1.0.0 and want set maxAge (for example 18 days) for cookie ACEGI_SECURITY_HASHED_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE. But when I open cookies in browser, this cookie expire in 2017 year...

```xml
<bean id="rememberMeServices" parent="txProxyTemplate">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDao"/>
                <property name="key" value="desknetRememberMe"/>
                <property name="parameter" value="rememberMe"/>
                <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="2"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="autoLogin">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Can anyone help me? What I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't really be using Acegi since it is no longer developed and has known vulnerabilities. But at least try the latest version to make sure you aren't seeing a bug.

Comment: Oh, it'll be fine if You be able to point out on vulnerabilities, please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are token and cookie. Cookie will expire in 5 year, and token expire as much as we set it via `property name="tokenValiditySeconds"`. And when token will expire, cookie must not be valid.

Comment: And old versions of Acegi-security has incorrect method that sets cookie - it sets cookie on 5 years. You need extend class TokenBasedRememberMeServices and override metod makeValidCookie().